# MVC UML class diagram

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, uml, class-diagram

I've have to work on a new project,written in C# mvc,the first thing i would like to do is create an UML class diagram.
Is there somewhere an example of how to do this?
Most examples show one controller with one view and one model.
But in this project there is per controller multiple Views and multiple ModelDto's
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do like below by using MS visio or any other UML tool.

**Just a sample looks like below** (methods and properties should differ)

[image]

Like above you can extend the above diagram for more views and models per controller.

**i.e.** In MVC you can have many Action methods inside a Controller and relevant view and model per Action method (in general).

For more details check [**Model View Controller Design Patterns**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42830/Model-View-Controller-Model-View-Presenter-and-Mod)

I hope this will help to you.